# Lack of javascript error messages with webpack when missing a dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've been recently frustrated when developing using Webpack, because whenever I introuduce a new dependency there are no printed errors if I forget to include the depending JavaScript file(s).

I have created an example project: https://github.com/manstie/test-django-webpack

In the example you can see I have purposely set up the `home` module to depend on the `utils` module.

When you run the server and load `localhost:8000` it is expected that you get a console log of `Here` and `You have successfully depended on utils.js` if you import all the necessary script files.

When `utils.js` is not included in `index.html`, `base.js` does not run at all - it silently fails, with no errors.

I am hoping there is a way to have errors show in the javascript console in these cases? I just can't find any resources or related questions on this issue.

Here is the `webpack.common.js` config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/bundles');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    utils: './home/js/utils.js',
    home: {
      import: './home/js/index.js',
      dependOn: ['utils']
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: dist,
    publicPath: 'bundles/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),  // deletes files inside of output path folder
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({ fileName: "../../manifest.json" }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic', // so that file hashes don't change unexpectedly?
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
            // or node_modules/packageName
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Here is the html with a missing dependency - I am using `django-manifest-loader` in order to prevent JavaScript caching issues

```html
...
{% load manifest %}
<script src="{% manifest 'runtime.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Is there a way to have webpack / js tell you about the missing dependency? -->
<!-- <script src="{% manifest 'utils.js' %}"></script> -->
<script src="{% manifest 'home.js' %}"></script>
...
```

And here are the js files:

index.js

```js
import { testFunc } from "./utils.js";

console.log("Here");

testFunc();
```

utils.js

```js
export function testFunc()
{
    console.log("You have successfully depended on utils.js");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am with you on this boat. Just lost three days figuring out this issue. I just created a feature request for this, any one interested can add their comments to the discussion: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/16251